# How to get Rails views to return its associated action names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this very simple controller for managing static pages within my Rails application:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
  end

  def features
  end

  def pricing
  end

end
```

How can I get a view template to return its own name, so I can do something like this:

```
# pricing.html.erb

<h1><%= my_own_name.capitalize %></h1>

# --> "Pricing"
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `params[:action]`, but probably you should create class variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**4.3 Routing Parameters**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters)

> The params hash will always contain the :controller and :action keys, but you should use the methods `controller_name` and `action_name` instead to access these values.

```
<h1><%= action_name.capitalize %></h1>
```

Comment: great solution, didn't know it.

Answer (score 3):

So:

```
  class PagesController < ApplicationController

    def pricing
      @action = params[:action]
    end

  end


  # pricing.html.erb
 <h1><%= @action.capitalize %></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if the content is static, I think that is a good pratice do generalize and do something like this:

config/routes.rb

```
get 'pages/:page_name  => 'pages#show'
```

controllers/pages_controller.rb

```
class PublicPagesController < ApplicationController
  def show_content
    render(params[:page_name])
  end
end
```

And in your view you can use the params[:page_name].